# convert [spacy list of pos_] to [list of tag_ ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, tagging, pos-tagger

```
['VERB', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT']


#how to convert this list to this :


['VBG', 'NNS', 'IN', 'NNS', 'CC', 'NN', '.']
```

** I have written code using spacy pos_ but now my input has been changed to tag_ **

Comment: What you tried so far?  If you are just map those specific string values create a dict with your mapping and iterate over it.

Comment: for different cases what can we do? is there any documentation for different cases brother  i mean doc for spacy tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611061/spacy-token-tag-full-list?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['VERB', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT']
lookup = {
        'ADP': 'IN',
        'CCONJ': 'CC',
        'NOUN': 'NNS',
        'NOUN': 'NN',
        'PUNCT': '.',
        'VERB': 'VBG'
}

result = [ lookup[w] for w in data ]
```

Comment: for different cases what can we do? is there any documentation for different cases brother