# Retrieve a list of model-specific POS tags using spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pos-tagger, spacy-3

I am looking for a way to get a list of **all possibly usable POS tags for a specific language** model in spaCy.

In [an answer to another question, spaCy's `TAG_MAP` has been referenced to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303305/11583484), but I am not sure how to access this. The documentation of spaCy says that [this attribute has been replaced](https://spacy.io/usage/v3#incompat). Since spaCy only uses a specific subset of all POS tags for a specific language, I would like to retrieve a list of all POS tags that are currently used with the initialized language model.

I did currently just set up a model this way:

```py
import spacy

tagger = spacy.load("de_dep_news_trf")

# TODO print(pos_tags)
```

Now, how do I print a list of all possible pos tags for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pretrained pipelines, you can check the labels on the [model page](https://spacy.io/models/de), under the "Label Scheme" entry.

If your pipeline has a tagger, like the German one does, you can do this:

```
tagger = nlp.get_pipe("tagger")
print(tagger.labels)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I also somehow get the tags of the universal pos tags, in case there isn't an existing set of tags for the chosen model?

Comment: This is the official documentation for the Universal POS tags. https://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/index.html

Comment: I was actually wondering if there is a way I can check whether a language model has a pipeline with a tagger, so I can use the universal POS tags in case the language doesn't have an own, predefined tagset.

Comment: I am not aware of any languages that have UPOS but not their own tagset. You can check which pretrained pipelines in spaCy have taggers using the model pages like the one linked to in my answer.